# Nginx+Tomcat - 504 timeout

Tags: tomcat, nginx, timeout

We receive a lot request on nginx some of them werent reached tomcat we just got Error 504 timeout on Nginx but nothing on Tomcat

Our configuration
Nginx routes traffic to virtual server (Windows Server) where is installed tomcat 7

We cant figure out where is problem
I thought if it is problem with tomcat we should see at least request from nginx on tomcat logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `504 Gateway Timeout` error may be a result of a network problem, that is - connection doesn't reach your Tomcat server at all, e.g. dropped by your firewall for some reason.  In this case it's normal that there will be nothing in Tomcat logs even assuming it properly logs everything it is able to log.

Additionally it may be impossible on some systems to obtain information about connections which were closed by clients while in listen queue, not sure about Windows though.  In any case I wouldn't expect Tomcat to log such connections by default.

In it's error log nginx will try to provide more information about a point at which the timeout happened.  With nothing in Tomcat logs I would expect something like `... while connecting to upstream ...`, which usually indicate either network problems or listen queue overflow as described above.

Comment: actually it shouldn't be network problem, we use LAN connection between  Nginx and tomcat

Comment: There is a minor difference between "shouldn't" and "not", which is often hit in practice.  In particular, I've seen similar issues many times due to stateful firewall between nginx and backend - either it runs out of states and starts to drop new connections, or it has state for a connection already closed and drops packets once hosts try to reuse the same address tuple. Don't guess, look into logs and use tcpdump/wireshark to see what happens on the wire.

Comment: you are right, our firewall allows only 100 connections per host. Thx